# My QuickSort code does not work for 1000000+ elements (one million elements or more)

Tags: c++, c++11, quicksort

I attempted to make my own sorting algorithm (call it MySort for now) and benchmark it against the sorting times of QuickSort. I use a random number generator to make an input file containing n random numbers, then provide this file as input to both MySort and QuickSort, and use std::chrono to time the time they take individually.

(At first I used an online compiler to check the times, but when I hit the limit of 10000 characters as input, I switched to doing it myself on my PC.)

So, for the first few tries (100 elements, 1000 elements, 10000 elements, 100000 elements), everything is working fine. I am getting a proper output time for the amount of time each sorting algorithm takes, but when I try to use 1000000 elements, QuickSort just doesn't give any output (does not seem to work at all), which is strange, because MySort **worked just fine**. I don't think it is a space issue, since MySort uses 2n additional space and works just fine.

The implementation of QuickSort I am using is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void quick_sort(int[],int,int);
int partition(int[],int,int);

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    cin>>n;

    int a[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();        
    quick_sort(a,0,n-1);
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

    duration <double, micro> d = stop - start;
    cout<<"Time taken = "<<d.count()<<endl;
    /*
    cout<<"\nArray after sorting:";

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
    */
    return 0;        
}

void quick_sort(int a[],int l,int u)
{
    int j;
    if(l<u)
    {
        j=partition(a,l,u);
        quick_sort(a,l,j-1);
        quick_sort(a,j+1,u);
    }
}

int partition(int a[],int l,int u)
{
    int v,i,j,temp;
    v=a[l];
    i=l;
    j=u+1;

    do
    {
        do
            i++;

        while(a[i]<v&&i<=u);

        do
            j--;
        while(v<a[j]);

        if(i<j)
        {
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
        }
    }while(i<j);

    a[l]=a[j];
    a[j]=v;

    return(j);
}
```

I tried looking around for solutions as to why it refuses to work for a million elements, but found nothing, besides the possibility that it may be a space issue, which seems unlikely to me considering MySort is working.

As for what exactly I get as output on feeding 1000000 elements in, when I execute both files on the command line, the output I get is (both run twice):

```
C:\Users\Zac\Desktop>MySortTest <output.txt                                      

Time Taken = 512129                                                                                                 

C:\Users\Zac\Desktop>MySortTest <output.txt                                      

Time Taken = 516131                                                                                                                                               

C:\Users\Zac\Desktop>QuickSortTest <output.txt                                                                                                                    

C:\Users\Zac\Desktop>QuickSortTest <output.txt                                                                                                                    

C:\Users\Zac\Desktop>
```

However, if I run them both for only **100000** elements each, this is what I get:

```
C:\Users\Zac\Desktop>MySortTest <output.txt                                      

Time Taken = 76897.1                                                                                                                                              

C:\Users\Zac\Desktop>MySortTest <output.txt                                      

Time Taken = 74019.4                                                                                                                                              

C:\Users\Zac\Desktop>QuickSortTest <output.txt                                   

Time taken = 16880.2                                                                                                                                              

C:\Users\Zac\Desktop>QuickSortTest <output.txt                                   

Time taken = 18005.3                                                                                                                                              

C:\Users\Zac\Desktop>
```

Seems to be working fine.

I am at my wits end, any suggestions would be wonderful.

Comment: Probably a stack overflow. Try using `std::vector<int>` instead of `int[]`. The latter isn't portable anyway.

Comment: `int a[n];` -- Don't do this.  Use `std::vector<int> a(n);`.  You have been fooled by the compiler you're using into believing that `int a[n]` is valid C++ code.

Comment: [Here is a link to your code failing to compile using Visual C++](https://rextester.com/ABT13070).  The error is as stated in the previous comments.  Another new programmer falls victim to the `g++` variable length array shenanigans.

Comment: Your bug is probably here: `int a[n];` VLAs are both not part of the c++ standard and are limited in size. I would expect a stack overflow from this.

Comment: Would g++ really allocate `int a[n];` with n == 100000 on the stack? I'm not disagreeing with the advice to use a `std::vector`, just wondering if the VLA is really the issue.

Comment: @john yes, it is really the issue.

Comment: `int a[n];` isn't standard c++. Also note that your stack size is limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cin>>n;

int a[n];
```

This is your bug. You should never do this for *three* reasons.

1. This is not valid C++. In C++, the dimension of any array should be a *constant expression*. You are fooled by a non-conformant extension of gcc. Your code will fail to compile with other compilers. You should *always* use gcc (and clang) in high conformance mode. For C++, it would be `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic-errors`
2. A large array local to a function is likely to provoke a stack overflow, since local variables are normally allocated on the stack and stack memory is usually very limited.
3. C-style arrays are bad, mkay? They don't know their own size, they cannot be easily checked for out-of-bounds access (`std::vector` and `std::array` have `at()` bounds-checking member functions), and they cannot be assigned or passed to functions or returned from functions. Use `std::vector` instead (or maybe `std::array` when the size is known in advance).

Comment: This is intended as a canonical answer to all C++ VLA questions similar to this one. I could not find a good thorough dupe so I decided to write it up. Please edit/improve as you see fit.

Comment: An addition to item `3.`, `std::vector` and `std::array` have `at()` member functions, so as to do easy sanity check for boundary conditions.  VLA's and arrays in general have no such error checking facilities.

Comment: Just posted an answer -- the code was flawed and the OP didn't realize it.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote it up again using vectors and it's working fine now. You guys have been of tremendous help.

Comment: @Zac I think you should still investigate the bug that PaulMcKenzie mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Let's remove the VLA's you're using and use `std::vector`.  Here is what the code looks like with a sample data of 10 items (but with a check for boundary conditions).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using vint = std::vector<int>;
void quick_sort(vint&, int, int);
int partition(vint&, int, int);

int main()
{
    int n = 10, i;
    vint a = { 7, 43, 2, 1, 6, 34, 987, 23, 0, 6 };
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    quick_sort(a, 0, n - 1);
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration <double, micro> d = stop - start;
    cout << "Time taken = " << d.count() << endl;
    return 0;
}

void quick_sort(vint& a, int l, int u)
{
    int j;
    if (l < u)
    {
        j = partition(a, l, u);
        quick_sort(a, l, j - 1);
        quick_sort(a, j + 1, u);
    }
}

int partition(vint& a, int l, int u)
{
    int v, i, j, temp;
    v = a[l];
    i = l;
    j = u + 1;

    do
    {
        do
           i++;
        while (a.at(i) < v&&i <= u);
        do
          j--;
        while (v < a[j]);
        if (i < j)
        {
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
    } while (i < j);

    a[l] = a[j];
    a[j] = v;
    return(j);
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/931548c78f3fa486).

You see that a `std::out_of_range` error is thrown on the line with the [std::vector.at()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) call.

Bottom line -- your code was flawed to begin with -- whether it was 10, 100, or a million items.  You are going out of bounds, thus the behavior is undefined.  Usage of `std::vector` and `at()` detected the error, something that VLA's will not give you.

Answer (score 1):

Besides VLA, your Quicksort always choose pivot as the first one. This may lead it to perform bad for worst cases. I don't know your `output.txt` but if the array has been already sorted, it runs `O(n^2)` because every partitioning would split into one element and the rest(half and half is the best). I think this is why it does not give any outputs for big inputs.

So I would suggest a couple of pivot-choosing heuristics that are commonly used.

- Choose it randomly
- Choose the median from the 3 elements - lowest/middle/highest index (`a[l]` / `v[(l+u)/2]` / `v[u]`)

Once you choose a pivot, you can just simply swap it with `v[lo]` which minimizes your code changes.